# Android String Resources from API

Tags: android, json, xml, string, api

It's possible to add dynamic strings resources in my application from my **API**. Stored with **json or XML** and with the same format like it is right now?

**I have already a multilingual website**, so i want in my application to have the same strings from an API! How can i store them in my application in strings resources files?

sorry for my english.

Comment: You can't modify application resources from code.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Strings resources files cannot be updated in Application lifecycle because there are compiled when you generate your APK. Maybe you need to look after storing your strings in a database or something else . See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As said before you can't modify the resources inside the app. But you can send the message/text in the required language from the server, I would implement a mechanism through which the app tells the server which language must use for the returned texts, and the app simply draws them when received. It is easy, simply change the focus from the app to the server.